# Regular expression to remove whitespace before and after = in java

Tags: java, regex

I want a regular expression which can remove spaces before or after `=` in java.

For example consider a string

```
String str="Name   =  Aniket";
```

I want the result to contain a strring which contains no spaces before or after `=`. That is result should contain `"Name=Aniket"`.
How to do it in java?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I want a regular expression which can remove spaces before **or** after = in java.

The following solution will remove all whitespace before **and** after a `=`, just as it should do in the example you provide.

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\s*=\\s*", "=");
```

will get rid of whitespace before and after every `=`, and leave the `=` where it was.